# Step by step guide to setup logback with slf4j under WildFly

Tags: wildfly, logback, slf4j, jboss-cli

Do we have any step by step guide to setup logback/slf4j with WildFly 16?

I have found following article but it seem pretty old and steps are manual:

https://blog.anotheria.net/devops/enable-logback-in-jboss/

I am creating a Docker image from jboss/wildfly base image.

I would like to use jboss-cli as much as possible to automate this process (Adding modules, amending existing modules etc..) in DockerFile.

I have also try to ask this on JBoss forums:
https://developer.jboss.org/message/989039#989039

Comment: Are you wanting to replace the logging subsystem with logback?

Comment: I would like to introduce logback replacing the default logging system.

Comment: You likely wouldn't be able to do that with CLI as IIRC you've got to update modules in order to replace the log manager. It's been a while since I tested it though.